# Bondage of jiva according to Sri Vaishnava Sampradaya

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, atma, ramanujacharya, vishishtadvaita

In the Vishishtadvaita philosophy followed by the Sri Vaishnava Sampradaya, the conditioned souls trapped in Samsara (the cycle of repeated birth and death) are referred to as Baddhas. How is the nature of the Baddhas' bondage explained by Ramanuja or any other Sri Vaishnava Acharya? Has the conditioned jiva always been in Samsara and is its bondage thus anādi (without beginning)? Or has the jiva once been with the Lord and *"fallen"* into this material world? Different Vaishnava sampradayas have different views on this issue, but what is the Siddhanta of Sri Vaishnavism?